# Populate a UIImageView from a .plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, plist

I have a .plist that references paths to .png files ( key value = "maps" ). I am able to add the images to an array with by using this code while loading the view:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad  {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"countries" ofType:@"plist"];  
NSArray *countries = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"maps" ascending:NO] autorelease];
self.sortedCountries = [countries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];

}
```

I am able to add the images to TableViewCells by using this method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

What I am trying to do is add these same images to an instance of UIImageView in a new ViewController. I have the ViewController set up properly, but how can I pull the images from the array do display in a UIImageView as I did for the UITableViewCells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you selecting the row of table following method get call-

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UserDetailVC* userDetailVC=[[UserDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserDetailVC" bundle:nil];
    [userDetailVC autorelease];
    //imp- set the image over here
        NSDictionary* tempDict=[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        userDetailVC.selectedImageView.image=[tempDict objectForKey:@"imageName"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:userDetailVC animated:YES];

    return nil;
}
```

so tried this, this will definitely gone help you.

Comment: Arrays don't have an `-objectForKey:` method, let alone an `-ObjectForKey:` one. Maybe you mean `-objectAtIndex:`?

Comment: Throws a "Request for 'image' in something not a structure or union"?

Comment: @mozzer set the image first in your UIImageView of newViewController by using your JSON Array or Dictionary and then call or push the newViewController.